# Redes Neurais com o pacote "AMORE" - R

Tags: r, inteligência-artificial

Caros colegas,
Eu estou tentando usar o pacote AMORE do R para rodar uma Rede Neural com novas funções de ativação, porém não consegui entender muito bem o manual e consequentemente não consegui implementar a nova função. Enfim, a função que eu quero implementar é a seguinte:

**Ordonez**

```
ord <- function(x){
   1-((1+0.5*exp(x))^(-1/0.5))#activation function Aranda-Ordonez
}
```

**DERIVATIVE Ordonez**

```
dord <- function(x){
   ((1+0.5*exp(x))^(-(1+0.5)/0.5))*exp(x)# derivative activation functionao Aranda-Ordonez
}
```

e a função do R que eu quero usar é esta, a qual eu quero apenas modificar a função do último neurônio `output.layer="custom"`:

```
select.activation.function(activation.function)

library(AMORE)

P <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,1,length=1000), 1000, replace=FALSE), ncol=1)

target <- P^2

net <- newff(n.neurons=c(1,3,2,1), learning.rate.global=1e-2, momentum.global=0.5,
error.criterium="LMS", Stao=NA, hidden.layer="tansig",
output.layer="custom", method="ADAPTgdwm")
result <- train(net, P, target, error.criterium="LMS", report=TRUE, show.step=100, n.shows=5 )


y <- sim(result$net, P)
```

Caso alguém já tenha usado ou tenha alguma dica a me dar, fico grato pela ajuda.

Atenciosamente,
Elisalvo

Comment: Vim nessa pergunta só pela carência... :/

Answer (score -1):

Consegui implementar redes neurais com o pacote `neuralnet` seguindo esse tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTg-qP9iGFY&index=3&t=899s&list=PLVbc4TTBBn6nuF3BTQms_y1j7wIV2inkL

Esse pacote me pareceu simples de implementar.
Também tentei o pacote `RNNS` mas sem sucesso.

Segue também uma lista de tutoriais: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVbc4TTBBn6nuF3BTQms_y1j7wIV2inkL

Caso adote o pacote `neuralnet` e tiver alguma dúvida, poderei te ajudar mais.
O pacote `AMORE` nunca utilizei.